# How do I move elements between stacks in recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, towers-of-hanoi

I have a tower of Hanoi problem. I have three stacks and I want to move the elements in a certain order in recursion with a method called move(). I'm supposed to use methods pop() and push() in another class that adds and removes elements from the stacks.

I have tried to implement this method but it only works for the first base case, eg. if n==1.

```
 public static void move(SpecialStack from, 
                         SpecialStack to, 
                         SpecialStack help, 
                         int n) {
   if (n == 1) {
 to.push(from.pop());
 }
   else {
     move(from, to, help, n-1);
     to.push(from.pop());
     move(help, to, from, n-1);
   }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 3;
    SpecialStack from = new SpecialStack(size);
    SpecialStack to = new SpecialStack();
    SpecialStack help = new SpecialStack();
    System.out.println("Start state");
    System.out.println("   From: " + from);
    System.out.println("   To:   " + to);
    System.out.println("   Help: " + help);
    move(from, to, help, size);
    System.out.println("End state");
    System.out.println("   From: " + from);
    System.out.println("   To:   " + to);
    System.out.println("   Help: " + help);
```

The error I get is my own from the push() method 'Number too high!' from the other class SpecialStack:

```
 import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SpecialStack {

  private ArrayList<Integer> specStack;

  public SpecialStack() {
    specStack = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  }

  public SpecialStack(int n) {         
    this.specStack = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
      int i;
      for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        specStack.add(i, n-i);
      }
    }


  public void push(int x) { 
    if (specStack.size() == 0) { 
      specStack.add(x);
    }
    else if (x > specStack.get(specStack.size() -1)) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Number too high");
    }
    else {
      specStack.add(x); 
    }
  }

  public int pop() { 
    if (specStack.size() == 0) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Empty stack");
    }
    else {
      int length = specStack.size() -1;
      int topNumber = specStack.get(length); 
      specStack.remove(length);
      return topNumber;
    }
  }

  public String toString() {
    String arrList = "[";
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < specStack.size(); i++) { 
      if (i == specStack.size() -1) {
        arrList = arrList + specStack.get(i);
      } 
      else {
        arrList = arrList + specStack.get(i) + ",";}
    }
  arrList = arrList + "]";
  return arrList;
  }
}
```

I don't understand why I get this error. And also, is the move() method correct? Thanks in advice!

Comment: What is a `SpecialStack`?  Can we see the code?

Comment: This is the class were pop and push methods are. I added the code

Comment: Will move *never* create a stack which is out-of-order?  That is, is the "number too high" condition correct to impose on *all* moves?

Answer (score 0):

You have a silly mistake in your code. In your else part, when `n > 1`, you should be doing

```
move(from, help, to, n-1);
```

instead of

```
move(from, to, help, n-1);
```

Remember, for anything greater than 1, you consider your 'help' queue to be your destination ( to ) queue for all but one of your pegs. Once that is done, you move your lowest peg to the original "to" queue, and repeat the moves considering your original "help" as "from" and your original "from" as "help". Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much!!